# GCP-Cloud Composer: Secret Manager access variable.json

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I try to configure Secret Manager for my Composer (ver 1.16, airflow 1.10) but I have a weird situation like below. In my Composer, I've used a `variable.json` file to manage Variables in Airflow

```
# variable.json
{
    "sleep": "False",
    "ssh_host": "my_host"
}
```

Then, I use this [article](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/secret-manager#configure-backend) to configure Secret Manager. Follow the instructions, I override the config with a section `secrets`

```
backend: airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend
backend_kwargs: {"variables_prefix":"airflow-variables", "sep":"-", "project_id": "my-project"}
```

And in my Secret Manager, I also created my secret : `airflow-variables-sercret_name` .

In fact, everything is fine, I could get my secret via (and of course, I don't have any problem with the service account)

```
from airflow.models.variable import Variable
my_secret = Variable.get('sercret_name')
```

But when I check the Logs, I found out that Airflow also tries to find the other variables in my `variables.json` file

```
2022-04-13 15:49:46.590 CEST airflow-worker Google Cloud API Call Error (NotFound): Secret ID airflow-secrets-sleep not found.
2022-04-13 15:49:46.590 CEST airflow-worker Google Cloud API Call Error (NotFound): Secret ID airflow-secrets-ssh_host not found.
```

So how could I avoid this situation, please? Or Did I miss understand something?
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

These errors are known when you use Secret Manager, but here are some workarounds below:

- Add a way to [skip Secret backend](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19251#issuecomment-958992113).
- File a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=460446&template=1162764) to lower the log priority; You can use [this as a template for your issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/216834179).
- Create logs exclusion in Cloud Logging.

About Logs Exclusion:

[Sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) control how Cloud Logging routes logs. Sinks belong to a given Google Cloud resource: Cloud projects, billing accounts, folders, and organizations. When the resource receives a log entry, it routes the log entry according to the sinks contained by that resource. The routing behavior for each sink is controlled by configuring the inclusion filter and [exclusion filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions) for that sink.

When you create a sink, you can set multiple exclusion filters, letting you exclude matching log entries from being routed to the sink's destination or from being ingested by Cloud Logging.

Comment: @nxh6991 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.